# range(25) print out for python

Tags: python, web-scraping, xbmc

I'm trying to scrape first 25 titles from a website and not sure why this isn't working? It brings up all the titles for some reason.

```
if section == 'latest':
    match=re.compile("<br>(.+?) - <a[^>]+?href='(.+?)'>(.+?)</a>").findall(html)
    for i in range(25):
        (year, url, name) = match[i]
        name = self.CleanTextForSearch(name)
        url = self.base_url + url
        self.AddContent(list,indexer,common.mode_File_Hosts,name + ' (' + year +')','',type, url=url, name=name, year=year)
```

Comment: Try this : `match=re.compile("<br>(.+?) - <a[^>]+?href='(.+?)'>(.+?)</a>").findall(html)[:25]`

Comment: thanks for the info but didn't work for me

Comment: actually that work thank you issue was on my end :)